# Sequential streams and shared state

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The [javadoc for `java.util.stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)  implies that "behavioral operations" in a stream pipeline must usually be stateless.  However, the examples it shows of how not to write a pipeline all seem to involve parallel streams.

To what extent does this apply to sequential streams?

In particular, I was looking over a colleague's code that looked essentially like this:

```
List<SomeClass> list = ...;
Map<SomeClass, String> map = new HashMap<>();
list.stream()
    .filter(x -> [some boolean expression])
    .forEach(x -> {
         if (map.containsKey(x) {
             throw new UserDefinedException("duplicates detected in input");
         } else {
             map.put(x, aStringFunction(x));
         }
     });
```

[The author had tried using `Collectors.toMap()`, but it threw an `IllegalStateException` when there were duplicates, and neither of us knew about the `toMap` that takes a `mergeFunction`.  That last would have been the best solution, but I'd like an answer anyway because of the more general principle involved.]

I was nervous about this code, since it wasn't clear to me whether the execution of the block in the `forEach` could overlap for different elements, even for a sequential stream.  The [javadoc for `forEach()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) is a bit ambiguous whether synchronization is necessary for accessing shared state in a sequential stream.  Eventually the author changed the code to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` and `map.putIfAbsent()`.

My question is: was I right to be nervous, or is the code above trustworthy?

Suppose the expression in the `filter()` did something that used some shared state.  Can we trust that it will work OK when using a sequential stream?

Comment: I wouldn't trust anything that manipulated state.  Avoid it if you possibly can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequential stream is by definition executes everything in the caller thread, thus if you are not going to parallelize your stream in future, you can safely use shared state without additional synchronization and concurrent-safe collections. So the current code is safe. Note however that it just looks dirty.

Answer (score 1):

If you rely on your `forEach` to be executed sequentially, consider using `forEachOrdered` instead even if the stream is sequential.  Not only will that get the explicit guarantee from the api that the code will be executed sequentially, it will make the code more self-documenting and provide some measure of protection against somebody coming along and changing your stream to parallel.